# Convert sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as string to utf8 using VBS

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, utf-8, vbscript

i have to write a script that converts a string from a MSSQL Server database in sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as into a value in an XML file, which is in UTF8 encoding.
Does anyone have an idea how to do in in VBS?

Thanks!

Comment: is the whole string XML?

Comment: the output has to be xml. the input is a query result from a MSSQL Server Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might need to add a bit more context to your question, but a first answer would be to query the database using ADODB, load your XML into MSXML2, use XPath to select the node in which you want to add your result then insert the string as the node text.

```vb
''#open the data
dim ado: set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ado.ConnectionString = "..."
ado.open
dim rs: set rs = ado.Execute("SELECT TOP 1 your_string FROM your_data_table")

''#open the XML
dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
xmldoc.async = false
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
''# you might also need setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns=..." depending on your XML 
xmldoc.load "path\to\your\XML"

''# store the string in the XML and save
xmldoc.selectSingleNode("//xpath/to/your/target/node").text = rs.fields["your_string"].value
xmldoc.save "path\to\your\output\xml"

rs.close
ado.close
```

If you're already at this point, let me know if you are having any specific problems

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but the problem has resolved itself.